# ContextMenuInfo returns null when calling showContextMenu - android

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I'm struggling to find a solution to a problem:

I want to open a contextMenu only for items in position 1 and above.

I register my listView :

```
registerForContextMenu(mDrawerList);
```

I register the OnItemLongClickListener :

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (position != 0)
                    mDrawerList.showContextMenu();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But in the `onCreateContextMenu` , `ContextMenuInfo` returns null,
If I remove the `OnItemLongClickListener` and leave it with the single call of the `registerForContextMenu`, then `ContextMenuInfo` isn't null..
:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        selectedPosition = info.position;
....
...
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: remove the long click listener... theoretically you need to register for context menu the items in the drawer, not the drawer itself, and you do not need to call "showContextMenu"

Answer (score 0):

remove the long click listener... theoretically you need to register for context menu  on the drawer itself, and you do not need to call "showContextMenu"

It should be like this:

in your drawer fragment you write this:

```
registerForContextMenu(mDrawerListview);
```

remove the onItemLongClickListener, because it should be triggered by the fact that you registered for context menu, your long click listener overrides it

Comment: Hi lena, i assume you meant that I should add the registerForContextMenu(convertView) inside my adapter right? if Yes, I still got the same problem.... the result is the same